# Google STS TradeFed fails with error: Failed to run command: com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationException: Can not find local config sts

Tags: android, cts, android-vts, android-tradefederation

This is related to Google STS. Similar to CTS and VTS, Google Trade Federation harness is used to run these test. However, unlike CTS and VTS, the STS suite fails when`run sts` command is invoked:

```
sts-tf > run sts
Failed to run command: com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationException: Can not find local config sts.
com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationException: Can not find local config sts.
    at com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationFactory$ConfigLoader.findConfigName(ConfigurationFactory.java:346)
    at com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationFactory$ConfigLoader.getConfigurationDef(ConfigurationFactory.java:269)
    at com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfigurationDef(ConfigurationFactory.java:492)
    at com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationFactory.internalCreateConfigurationFromArgs(ConfigurationFactory.java:600)
    at com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationFactory.createConfigurationFromArgs(ConfigurationFactory.java:528)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler.createConfiguration(CommandScheduler.java:1255)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler.internalAddCommand(CommandScheduler.java:1287)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler.addCommand(CommandScheduler.java:1168)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.Console$25.run(Console.java:704)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.Console$25.run(Console.java:687)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.Console.executeCmdRunnable(Console.java:926)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.Console.run(Console.java:1028)
    at com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.command.CompatibilityConsole.run(CompatibilityConsole.java:105)
```

There is no clue with regards to what "local config" it is expecting. Some Google search led me to this:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/tradefederation/+/master/src/com/android/tradefed/config/ConfigurationFactory.java#346

Does anyone know what is the catch here?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to run it as sts-engbuild ?

Full command would be like this.

```
run sts-engbuild -d -o -s <Serial_ID>
```